# Search-and-Replace RegEx Capture Group with a Number

Tags: regex, visual-studio, capture-group

I'm trying to use the Visual Studio editors Regular Expressions to find and replace text using capture-groups, but have run into a problem.

I'm trying to find and capture a set of 5 Alpha-Numerics:

```
(\w{5})
```

And search-replace that group to append a "1" after it:

```
$11
```

Here I really mean `$1` *The Captured Group* + `1` *Text to append*

*Examples:*

```
 227TW ==> 227TW1
 1053X ==> 1053X1
```

However, it obviously interprets `$11` as "Capture Group Eleven".

How can I properly make the Search/Replace understand that `$1` and `1` are separate elements?

Things I've tried, that failed:

```
$1(1)  : 227TW ==> 227TW(1)
$1\1   : 227TW ==> 227TW\1
$1 1   : 227TW ==> 227TW 1
$1^1   : 227TW ==> 227TW^1
($1)1  : 227TW ==> (227TW)1
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Turns out the right answer is:

```
${1}1
```

The curly-braces around the number identify the capture group without confusing it with the next digit.

Comment: great answer!! Actually I wanted to suggest to step approach, e.g. first replace to `$1##1##` or whatever string you won't find in your input, then replace `##1##`to `1`

Comment: Not sure if this doesn't work anymore or if I'm doing something wrong but that won't work for me - it doesn't match a group and replaces with `${1}` litterally.

Comment: @Ten: It sounds like you do not have the "Use Regular Expressions" checkbox selected.

Comment: @abelenky thank you for your answer - unfortunately I do: it matches using the regex and it's just the capture group replacements that aren't identified as such as soon as I add the `{}` :(

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if VS supports lookbehind, but if it does, you can use:

- Find: `(?<=\w{5})` zero-length assertion to make sure we have 5 word characters before current position
- Replace: `1`